# Transaction fees above Transaction Value - Unsustainable long-term?

Tags: transaction-fees, dust

1. Does Bitcoin Core support that transaction fees are higher than the transaction value itself? If so, why is that?
2. Should there be a dust limit to cap transaction fees (I.e. max transaction value)? Would that require a (soft) fork?

Comment: why should it not allow this?

Comment: The dust limit is something that restricts output sizes. Transaction fees are collected into the block reward, they don’t create separate outputs. Regarding the ratio of fees to sent amount, are you asking why the protocol doesn’t disallow this or why the wallet creates such transactions?

Comment: Yes, why does the protocol not restrict low value transactions where the fee is much higher than the transaction value. Would solve spamming potentially or am I missing something…